# Put json result from php script into divs jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have two divs, each one should have a record name from a json result.

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

My json file is as follows :

```
 [{"Name":"name1","Instruction":"instr"},
 {"Name":"name2","Instruction":"instr again"}]
```

I want to put in the first div's value, the ‘Name‘ value of the first record, same for the second div but with the second record.
I'm using jQuery :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("data/result.php",
                function(data) {
                    //alert("Data: " + data);
                    $('div.first').append(data.Name); //data.Name returns undefined
                }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data` is an Array -> `data[0].Name`, also make sure you are setting the correct `contentType` (`json`) when using `POST`.

Comment: it still returns undefined

Comment: Oh. It's not an Ajax request. use JSON.parse on data. Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: thank you both for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

as far as you are using post for you ajax call, the data returns as a json string, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("data/result.php",
            function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $('div.first').append(data[0].Name);
                $('div.second').append(data[1].Name);
            }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned you need to parse the result as json. You could use the built in parser in jquery. Like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'data/result.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function (data) {
            $('div.first').append(data[0].Name);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can give a datatype with a request:

```
$.post('data/result.php',function(data) { },'JSON');
```

If you are not posting any information, why not just use $.get ? (it's the same syntax btw)

```
$.post('data/result.php',function(data) {
    var $first = $('div.first'),
        $second = $('div.second');
    $first.text(data[0].Name);
    $second.text(data[1].Name);
},'JSON');
```

Also, if you use **.append(..)** it will be appended to whatever is already in the div. If that is your intention, use **.append(...)**. However, if you want to replace the content of it, even if it is empty, use **.text(...)** or **.html(...)**